# How to fix HololensWorldManager failed to return a world coordinate system?

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, hololens-emulator

I'm working on an augmented reality app using Unity and Mixed Reality toolkit for Hololens. The error "HoloLensWorldManager failed to return a world coordinate system" appears when previewing app.

Using 2019.1, and when running Hololens apps via the player I receive a continual stream of HoloLensWorldManager failed to return a world coordinate system! errors. This only occurs when the platform is set to UWP

Note: I saw this issue with the MRTK for Unity team here: https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/4066 who suggested that it is likely to be a bug with the Windows MR package

Have anyone a solution in order to fix this issue?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: Based on the issue from GitHub, you are using MRTK v2 RC1, is it helpful using the latest version [Microsoft Mixed Reality Toolkit v2.0.0 RC2.1](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/releases/tag/v2.0.0-RC2.1)?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, but on the net someone said he solved setting manually Virtual Reality setting to true.
To do that:

- Go to Projet Settings
- Select Player on the left menu
- Go to XR Settings and make sure you have flagged che checkbox

Hope it works for you!